# Error in Magento 2.4.6, Call to a member function create() on null

Tags: magento2, php8, magento2.4.6

During the process of the update, when i run the query for create a customerCart i have the following error:
Query:

```
 {
  customerCart{
    id
  }
}

[2023-03-22T14:37:58.926211+00:00] report.ERROR: Call to a member function create() on null

GraphQL (2:3)
1: {
2:   customerCart{
     ^
3:     id
 {"exception":"[object] (GraphQL\\Error\\Error(code: 0): Call to a member function create() on null at /var/www/html/vendor/webonyx/graphql-php/src/Error/Error.php:153)
[previous exception] [object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function create() on null at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php:118)"} []
```

I thought at the beginning that was due to from another custom module, but it was not the case, any suggestions? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, the problem was the customer attribute with the custom source that extended `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table`. I had to override the getSpecificOptions method in the attrribute source file - which was not necessary before 2.4.6